# How to paste multiple lines of text into python input

Tags: python, textinput

I currently have the following line of code for an input:

```
rawdata = raw_input('please copy and paste your charge discharge data')
```

When using [Enthought's GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthought) with [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) and I run my script, I can copy and paste preformatted text fine which pulls with it the \t and \n. When trying to paste data into a terminal style version of the script, it, however, tries to process each line of data rather than accepting it as bulk. How can I fix this?

More relevant lines of code:

```
rawed = raw_input('Please append charge data here: ')
    time, charge = grab_and_sort(rawed)

def grab_and_sort(rawdata):

    rawdata = rawdata.splitlines()
    ex = []
    why = []

    for x in range(2 , len(rawdata)):
        numbers = rawdata[x].split('\t')
        ex.append(numbers[0])
        why.append(numbers[1])

    ex = array(ex)
    why = array(why)

    return (ex, why)
```

Comment: How does it know when to stop reading input? A blank line, a stopword, something like that?

Comment: Added some more relavent data. I don't know how it knows to stop reading the input?

Comment: `raw_input` and `input` stop waiting for keyboard input on a newline character, which you get by pressing Enter. That newline is not included in the output. If you want your data to include newline characters, you will have to determine how you want to tell the program to stop waiting for input, and then have the program keep asking for input until this condition is met.

Comment: @AdamSchulz Welcome to StackOverflow. Even though your question has been asked in a different way before, you can still accept or vote for answers you found helpful.

Comment: Is the code (as posted) actually syntactically correct?

Comment: OK, the OP may have [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than a month ago"*

Answer (score 5):

`raw_input` accepts any input *up until a new line character is entered*.

The easiest way to do what you are asking it to accept more entries, until an end of file is encountered.

```
print("please copy and paste your charge discharge data.\n"
      "To end recording Press Ctrl+d on Linux/Mac on Crtl+z on Windows")
lines = []
try:
    while True:
        lines.append(raw_input())
except EOFError:
    pass
lines = "\n".join(lines)
```

Then do something with the whole batch of text.

Comment: Ctrl-D doesn't stop input in my shell.

Comment: What shell do you use?

Comment: Tried it on both cmd and Powershell.

Comment: Windows has a different "EOF" key command, I've updated the answer.