# When does python terminal automatically press enter when pasting something

Tags: python, python-3.x

Title really seems off the point, but what I am trying to ask is this:

For example, I have an input variable called answer

```
answ = input("> ")
```

Whenever I run the code and paste something into the input it automatically goes through and does not allow me to edit anything.

But, I also have another input variable that is not really different from the first one and that one allows me to edit out my input once I paste anything into

My question is, why are those 2 inputs different.

Please ask me in detail on what you didn't get about my question. I might be explaining very poorly

Comment: Probably, there is a trailing enter right at the end in the copied data.

Comment: Didn't know that was possible, although that's true. How  can i make sure that the paste is RAW always.

Comment: Please create a [mcve], what does "does not allow me to edit anything" mean?

Comment: You should not include "enter" while copying and that's the quickest solution (maybe only).

Comment: There is no way to remove the enter from the pasted text if one is present. You could put your input into a loop that prints the text back and asks 'Is that really your input?' - but that is clumsy and awkward. Copying without enter in it is the way to go.

Comment: @Sayse https://i.imgur.com/WcXpcJz.gif In this GIF example you can see that I did not press enter and it automatically made an input for me

Comment: [How to paste multiple lines of text into python input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34889012/1324033)

Comment: ctrl+shift + (C or V)